# Best way to store a base64 encoded value in MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, base64

I have a value I'd like to store in my DB, does the Collation make any difference how a string like this

```
YToyOntzOjIwOiJUeXBlX29mX29yZ2FuaXNhdGlvbiI7czoyMDoiTWVtYmVyIG9mIFBhcmxpYW1lbnQiO3M6ODoiUG9zdGNvZGUiO3M6NzoiUEUxIDFKQSI7fQ==
```

Might be stored? Also, the only way I seem to be able to write these values to the DB is by using a `BLOB` this seems to be a really rather wrong way of storing it.

Comment: Since it's *already* base64, why not just a CHAR/VARCHAR? BINARY, VARBINARY, and BLOB are suitable ways - depending - for storing (not base64-encoded) binary data. Since it appears to be a small value, I would suggest BINARY vs. BLOB.

Comment: brilliant, for some reason i did not think to use Binary! :)

Comment: Ah, sometimes I like to decode things posted on SO. Note that with that kind of structure, it will be troublesome to properly query certain data out of it.

Comment: @JamieHutber, is it necessary to `base64`ing your data? Length of data string is longer and unqueryable (as HamZa mentioned above). I'm just curious, not demanding.

Comment: @TheFrost I was more concerned since it seems like JSON when it's decoded. It's a SQL antipattern.

Comment: hummm,  I must say, on some of the data I would be needed to query the data. Not all of it mind you.

Comment: @JamieHutber Have you considered storing the data in its unencoded form? If all rows contain data with roughly the same structure, you would certainly benefit from storing the data in a normalised structure.

Comment: Well, currently I'm using BLOB's in the `db` to store my encrypted data. But for me this seems rather inefficient way to store details. I'm looking to maximise the `db`'s efficiency.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you did the math wrong. Your base64 string is 125 bytes long. The same data in a normalised table would take about 20 bytes. Also, ask yourself how you would proceed to find all rows where "Postcode = 'PE1 1JA'".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The collation only makes a difference if you need to `ORDER BY` or search the column. These base64 encoded items are probably not going to be searched or sorted.

If your encoded items are guaranteed to be less than 64K bytes in length, define your column like this:

```
   `columnname` TEXT CHARACTER SET ascii,
```

This is exactly what's needed for a base64 encoded variable; the encoding process turns everything into displayable ASCII.

If the items will be less than 16 megabytes in length, but some will be longer than 64k, use `MEDIUMTEXT` instead of `TEXT`.

**Edit** years later.

The OQ encoded string, decoded, is a serialized php object:

```
a:2:{s:20:"Type_of_organisation";s:20:"Member of Parliament";s:8:"Postcode";s:7:"PE1 1JA";}
```

Observation 1: lots of this stuff gets stored in text columns without encoding it, using the utf8 or utf8mb4 character set. Lots? Yes. WordPress stores option data this way.

Observation 2: If it can be translated to JSON, you could use the JSON data type in recent versions of MySQL. JSON searches still aren't sargable, but they are structured.