# How to save a picture in database sent from android by base64 encoding through PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql, base64

I am doing a project a part of which includes sending captured image to 
server. I am using 000webhost as my server. From my android app I capture an image and send it to server through PHP. Help me please with any available resource/link/code/example how to save the picture in database. So I can apply several operation or queries on that.
For checking my app temporarily I have aploaded pictures which are being saved in a folder of my server. The code follow, doing this job:

`

```
     // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if(isset($_POST['ImageName'])){
    $imgname = $_POST['ImageName'];
    $imsrc = base64_decode($_POST['base64']);
    $fp = fopen($imgname, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $imsrc);
    if(fclose($fp)){
      echo "success uploading image";
      }else{
          echo "Error uploading image";
       }

     }
    ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image path in the data base or you can save the base64 itself, as a base64 is a string. Note that a base64 is a long string, so have that in mind when you create the column to save that info. You can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198780/best-way-to-store-a-base64-encoded-value-in-mysql-db).